# Regexp_replace a number only when appears alone

Tags: qgis, sql, regular-expression

I want to use regexp_replace expression to replace some numbers within a expression, but only when this numbers appear alone.

For exemple:

If have the expression '1 and 2' I want it to replace for 'B3 and B4' where B3 replaces 1 and B4 replaces 2… but when I already have'B1 and A2' and don't want it to be replaced by 'AB3 and AB4'. although I have several regex_replace inside one another's and what is happening is: it firsts replaces '1 and 2' by 'B3 and B4' but then replaces 'B3 and B4' because I indicate replacements for 3 and for 4.

It might be obvious but I'm not getting there.

---

I have this

```
CASE WHEN  "DIC" =8 THEN
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
"DIC_RP",'10','A2'),'9','A2'),'8','A3'),'7','A3'),'6','A3'),'5','A4'),'4','
A4'),'3','A4'),'2','A5'),'1','A5')
```

When the text I want to replace has ‘5 and 4’, I should have ‘A4 and A4’ as final result, but this expression is replacing two times the number four (4) so it gives me a wrong result -> ‘AA4 and AA4’. How can I manage to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide example data covering all possible combinations you want replaced and kept? Currently I'd say "run CASE WHEN" and define every replacement manually, but that might be many WHENs.

Comment: check out regexr.com

Answer (score 4):

You can search for the beginning of the text or a space followed by a number:

```
regexp_replace('1 and 2 not B3','(^|\\s)[0-9]','\\1999')

-->  999 and 999 not B3
```

`(^|\\s)`: 1st capture group
`^`: beginning of the string
`|`: or
`\\s`: a space
`[0-9]`: followed by any number
`\\1` `999`: replace by the 1st capture group (to preserve the space) and number 999. Don't write a space between the two!

Comment: I don't work with QGIS, but with Python the regex would need to be `'(^|\\s)[0-9]+'` to work with numbers with more than one digit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the always forgotten metacharacter `\b` to match word and number boundaries:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace('1 and 1,2 and not B1,A2','\\b1\\b','B3'),'\\b2\\b','B4')
```

The result is: `B3 and B3,B4 and not B1,A2`